# Uninstalling Showing Unexpected Packages

Tags: debian, uninstall

I've gone from a single server to multi server setup in the past few weeks. I am now ready to uninstall *Let's Encrypt* / *Certbot* from the original server.  (I've [setup SSL termination with *HA Proxy*](https://kevinbentlage.nl/blog/lets-encrypt-with-haproxy/).)

I've tried `apt remove --purge letsencrypt`.  But this is showing packages I am still requiring:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bsdmainutils cpp-8 dh-python libapache2-mod-php7.3 libasan5 libbind9-161 libbison-dev libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-system1.67.0 libc-dev-bin libcwidget3v5 libdns1104 libdns1110 libevent-2.1-6 libf2fs-format4 libf2fs5 libgfortran5
  libicu63 libip6tc0 libiptc0 libirs161 libisc1100 libisc1105 libisccc161 libisccfg163 libisl19 liblinear3 libllvm7 liblua5.2-0 liblwres161 libmemcachedutil2 libmpdec2 libperl5.28 libprocps7 libpython3.7 libpython3.7-minimal
  libpython3.7-stdlib linux-libc-dev ncal perl-modules-5.28 php-symfony-debug php7.3 php7.3-bcmath php7.3-fpm php7.3-mysql php7.3-pgsql php7.3-soap php8.0-memcached python3-asn1crypto python3-future python3-mock python3-pbr python3.7
  python3.7-minimal usb.ids
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  letsencrypt*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
After this operation, 30.7 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I am at the tail end of PHP7.3 with just 1 script remaining using it.  I am not fluent in Python.  Would someone please explain the logic that has determined the list of packages the computer doesn't see as being required any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt` keeps track, for each package, whether it was installed because it was explicitly requested or because it was automatically pulled in as a dependency. Packages which are automatically installed become candidates for auto-removal when all the packages which need them are themselves removed.

Determining why packages become auto-removable in a specific context requires knowing the history of the system; there isn’t enough information here to say.

However, there’s no cause for alarm: `apt` is telling you that these packages are candidates for auto-removal, not that it is going to remove them. The packages will only be removed if you ask `apt` to remove them (`apt autoremove` for example). As it is, if you confirm the command in your question, only `letsencrypt` will be removed.

You can avoid this in future by [marking them as manually installed](https://manpages.debian.org/apt-mark), for example with

```
sudo apt-mark manual bsdmainutils
```